# React froala Super expression must either be null or a function not undefined

Tags: reactjs, froala

I am trying to use froala editor in my react code and It is working perfectly in my local. But in production it is crashing. It is just a blank page. When I opened console there is a error message **Super expression must either be null or a function not undefined**. If I remove froala editor then it is working fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css';
import 'froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css';
import FroalaEditorComponent from 'react-froala-wysiwyg';

const Editor = (props) => {
  
  return <FroalaEditorComponent  {...props} />;
};

export default Editor;
```

and this is my webpack config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    main: ['./client/app/main'],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/dist'),
    filename: '[name].app.bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules[\/\\](?!(swiper|dom7|@jimp\/core|d3-array|d3-scale|file-type|react-wordcloud|striptags)[\/\\])/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          babelrc: false,
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'],
          plugins: [
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true }],
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
          ]
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'

      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './client/app'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
    // These extensions are tried when resolving a file

    enforceExtension: false,
    // If false it will also try to use no extension from above

    moduleExtensions: ['-loader'],
    // These extensions are tried when resolving a module

    enforceModuleExtension: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      test: /\.js?$/,
      deleteOriginalAssets: true,
    })
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Any help would be really thankfull

Comment: Any progress on this issue ? I am also looking for an answer

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg/issues/224) about what seems to be the problem.

Comment: yes @challet. We have fixed it by adding it in webpack exclude. 
```
exclude: /node_modules[\/\\](?!(swiper|dom7|@jimp\/core|d3-array|d3-scale|file-type|react-wordcloud|striptags|froala-editor|react-froala-wysiwyg)[\/\\])/ 
```